# WPF Datagrid binding error when NOT auto-generating columns

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I have a simple datatgrid that works when I define it in the following way:

```
    <DataGrid             
        ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollectionViewSource.View}"        
        Style="{DynamicResource FTC_DataGridStyle}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

If I remove the AutoGenerateColumns="True"  and try to define my columns as follows, I get an error:

```
     <DataGrid             
        ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollectionViewSource.View}"        
        Style="{DynamicResource FTC_DataGridStyle}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding idCertification}" Header="ID" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{DynamicResource IDCellStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding chrTitle}" Header="TITLE" Width="130" CellStyle="{DynamicResource TextCellStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding chrDetail}" Header="DETAIL" Width="300" CellStyle="{DynamicResource TextCellStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding chrProvider}" Header="PROVIDER" Width="130" CellStyle="{DynamicResource TextCellStyle}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns> />
    </DataGrid>
```

The error i get is:

> {"'Add value to collection of type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.' Line
>   number '31' and line position '32'."} {"Operation is not valid while
>   ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with
>   ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."}

I use the MVVM pattern and the binding of EmployeeCollectionViewSource is a collectionviewsource that is populated from an ObservableCollection generated from entity framemowrk.

I have tried removing columns and double checked the binding names, I can't figure out where this error is coming from.  There are no errors shown in the output window.

**QUESTION**
Can you please help me resolve this error so I can define my column manually?

**ADDITIONAL DETAIL:**
The following is my viewmodel class:

```
    Public Class EmployeeCertificationViewModel
        Inherits ViewModelBase

#Region "DECLARATIONS"

        Public Const CertificationCollectionPropertyName As String = "EmployeeCertifications"
        Public Const EmployeeCollectionViewSourcePropertyName As String = "EmployeeCollectionViewSource"

        ''this is a holder for the employee data service
        Private _EmployeeAccess As IEmployeeDataService

        Private _EmployeeCertifications As New ObservableCollection(Of certification)
        Private _EmployeeCollectionViewSource As New CollectionViewSource

        ''tracks if employee validation is coming from navigation or listview selecteditemchanged
        Private FlagNavigating As Boolean = False
        Private _NavigationService As INavigationService

        Private _ModelService As IModelService
        Private Context As FTC_Context

#End Region

#Region "PROPERTIES"

        Public Property EmployeeCertifications As ObservableCollection(Of certification)
            Get
                Return Me._EmployeeCertifications
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of certification))
                Me._EmployeeCertifications = value
                RaisePropertyChanged(CertificationCollectionPropertyName)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property EmployeeCollectionViewSource As CollectionViewSource
            Get
                Return Me._EmployeeCollectionViewSource
            End Get
            Set(value As CollectionViewSource)
                If _EmployeeCollectionViewSource Is value Then
                    Return
                End If
                _EmployeeCollectionViewSource = value
                RaisePropertyChanged(EmployeeCollectionViewSourcePropertyName)
            End Set
        End Property


#End Region

#Region "COMMANDS"

#End Region

#Region "METHODS"

#End Region

#Region "CONSTRUCTOR"
        Public Sub New(NavService As INavigationService, EmployeeService As IEmployeeDataService, ModelService As IModelService)

            _ModelService = ModelService
            Context = _ModelService.NewContext

            _NavigationService = NavService
            _EmployeeAccess = EmployeeService

            EmployeeCertifications = EmployeeService.Get_Certification(Context)
            EmployeeCollectionViewSource.Source = EmployeeCertifications

        End Sub

#End Region

    End Class
```

Comment: If you remove one DataColumn at a time from the xaml, do you ever stop getting that error? I suspect one of your columns is the issue.  If so, which column is the problem.

Comment: @DJBurb I tried removing the columns one at a time, they all throw the error

Comment: Where do you set your DataContext?

Comment: its set in the usercontrol xaml declaration.  All other bindings work properly and if you remove the manually defined columns it works.  So I don't think it is the datacontext declaration.

Comment: aha! That's what I was asking you to do earlier.  So you have to remove all of the manually defined columns for it work? Correct?  Then what if you add them back one at a time.

Comment: @JKing did you test your XAML without a `ItemsSource` if this will work . Test it with a fake`ItemsSource` which provides the properties if this will also work use your `EmployeeCollectionViewSource.View` and add his items from a mocke

Comment: Thanks for the effort guys.  After hours of trying I got frustrated and just restarted the computer, then I rebuilt my solution which references an Entity Framework Project as the data model in a separate project in the solution.  I had made some changes to the table column names earlier yesterday.  Anyway, it all works now exactly as I first posted it, with no error.  I hate this, now I don't know why it was there in the first place, my only guess was that rebuilding the entity framework project fixed something. bah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is **true** by default. If you want to define your own columns you have to set it to false explicitly. Otherwise you will have both column types (autogenerated and own defined) at the same time.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But your real problem seems to be the additional **`/>`** after `</DataGrid.Columns>` in your code. Remove it and the exception should be gone.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I added the AutoGenerateColumns="False", but the error remains exactly as it was

Comment: I eventually got my solution working, and I did not need to explicitly set AutoGenerateColumns to false, if I manually set them it seems to recognise that

Comment: You're partially right and I think I've found the problem too. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: ha,  that was it, I rebuilt the page after restarting my computer and must have removed the extra />.  Good catch, thanks.